# R fails to write table to PostgreSQL via rPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to use R to write table to PostgreSQL. See the R code below; make some reproducible data frame first:

```
> Time<-c('201512', '201511', '201510')
> Department<-c('ABC', 'BCA', 'NBA')
> Pro_Type<-c('standard', 'maintain', 'sustaining')
> Man_month<-c('111.4', '124.1', '232.1')
> ID<-c('1','2', '3')
> melt_short<-data.frame(Time, Department, Pro_Type, Man_month, ID)
> melt_short
   Time  Department   Pro_Type Man_month ID
1 201512        ABC   standard     111.4  1
2 201511        BCA   maintain     124.1  2
3 201510        NBA sustaining     232.1  3
```

then creates the connection:

```
 require("RPostgreSQL")

# loads the PostgreSQL driver
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
# creates a connection to the postgres database
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "XXX",
             host = "XXX.XX.XX.XXX", port = 5432,
             user = "postgres", password = XXXXXX)
```

then I create a table in PostgreSQL DB:

```
 CREATE TABLE dms_melt
(
  "Time" numeric,
  "Department" character(1),
  "Pro_type" character(1),
  "Man_month" numeric,
  "ID" numeric NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dms_melt_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
 ALTER TABLE dms_melt
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

Finally execute the write table code and got the error:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "dms_melt", value = melt_short, append = T,row.names=F)

Error in postgresqlgetResult(new.con) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  value too long for   
type character(1) CONTEXT:  COPY dms_melt, line 1, column Department: "ABC"
```

It should be not so hard but I've been searching for solution for a while but in vain. And actually I've used the "mtcars" data set to write table and with no problem.

```
data(mtcars)
df <- data.frame(carname = rownames(mtcars), 
                 mtcars, 
                 row.names = NULL)
df$carname <- as.character(df$carname)

dbWriteTable(con, "cartable", 
             value = df, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

inserted the PostgreSQL which I created as:

```
CREATE TABLE cartable
(
  carname character varying,
  mpg numeric(3,1),
  cyl numeric(1,0),
  disp numeric(4,1),
  hp numeric(3,0),
  drat numeric(3,2),
  wt numeric(4,3),
  qsec numeric(4,2),
  vs numeric(1,0),
  am numeric(1,0),
  gear numeric(1,0),
  carb numeric(1,0)
 )
 WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
 );
 ALTER TABLE cartable
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and ideas.

Comment: @Parfait: Hi, it's factor in the data frame. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention to the data type of the following two table columns:

```
...
"Department" character(1),
"Pro_type" character(1),
...
```

Now let's look at the data you're trying to insert:

```
   Time  Department   Pro_Type Man_month ID
1 201512        ABC   standard     111.4  1
2 201511        BCA   maintain     124.1  2
3 201510        NBA sustaining     232.1  3
```

Now the error message:

```
Error in postgresqlgetResult(new.con) :
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  value too long for
type character(1) CONTEXT:  COPY dms_melt, line 1, column Department: "ABC"
```

The `character(N)` data type in PostgreSQL is a fixed-length string type. Every value in that column must be a string of characters with length N. For `character(1)`, this means every value must comprise a single character.

The value `'ABC'` is a string with length 3. It is too long for the `character(1)` data type.

You may be confusing the R character vector type with the SQL character type. In R, each element of a character vector is a variable length string. Ironically, you can construct a character vector in R with the syntax `character(N)` where N is the number of variable-length string elements in the resulting vector. In SQL, you can view a column as being a vector, but data types always refer to the scalar type of a single cell value. The N in the SQL syntax `character(N)` refers to number of characters in each string.

The reason your `mtcars` test worked is because the only string column in that table is `carname` which has data type `character varying` with no length specification. From the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-character.html):

> If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size. The latter is a PostgreSQL extension.

So, you can solve the problem by using `character varying` (or its more concise name `varchar`) for these two columns. You can omit the length specification just as in the `mtcars` schema, or if you are aware of a contractual length limit on the values of those columns you can specify `varchar(N)` where N is the length limit. Also, if `Department` values are always 3 characters long, you have the option of going with `char(3)` for a fixed-length type.

Summary:

```
SQL
==========

character(N)            fixed-length strings of length N
char(N)                 alias for character(N)
character               alias for character(1)
char                    alias for character(1)
character varying(N)    variable-length strings of maximum length N
varchar(N)              alias for character varying(N)
character varying       variable-length strings of unlimited length
varchar                 alias for character varying

R
==========

character(N)            vector of length N of variable-length strings
```